# How can I enable touchpad functions like two finger scrolling etc?

Tags: touchpad

How can I enable touchpad functions like two finger scrolling, etc., on Ubuntu 14.04?

When I used Windows those functions worked, here they don't.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.